# Re-arrangement of equation

Tags: functional-equations

This type of question might be voted down or frowned upon, but if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. I have worked through a question getting the following result:

$$
\frac{\nu{'}}{\nu}=\frac{(\hat{\Omega}\cdot{\beta}-1)}{(\hat{\Omega{'}}\cdot{\beta}-1)+\frac{h\nu}{\gamma{m_e}c^2}(\hat{\Omega}\cdot\hat{\Omega}'-1)}
$$

Now, the problem is: I think I have done this question correctly. That is my assumption. However, the question asks to show that:

$$
\frac{\nu{'}}{\nu}=\frac{(1-\hat{\Omega}\cdot{\beta})}{(1-\hat{\Omega{'}}\cdot{\beta})+\frac{h\nu}{\gamma{m_e}c^2}(1-\hat{\Omega}\cdot\hat{\Omega}')}
$$

So my question is this: have I gone wrong or am I able to re-arrange my expression into the expression I need to show...?

Comment: You're right there, just multiply by $-1$ on top and bottom...

Comment: Could you show me please...I'm struggling to see this.

Comment: Note that we have (for instance) $$-1\cdot (\hat{\Omega}\cdot{\beta} - 1) = 1-\hat{\Omega}\cdot{\beta}$$Also, as with any fraction, we're allowed to multiply the numerator and denominator both by $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get

$$\frac{\nu{'}}{\nu}=\frac{(\hat{\Omega}\cdot{\beta}-1)}{(\hat{\Omega{'}}\cdot{\beta}-1)+\frac{h\nu}{\gamma{m_e}c^2}(\hat{\Omega}\cdot\hat{\Omega}'-1)}$$

changed into the correct form, we have $(\hat{\Omega}\cdot{\beta}-1)=-(1-\hat{\Omega}\cdot{\beta})$ and $(\hat{\Omega{'}}\cdot{\beta}-1)+\frac{h\nu}{\gamma{m_e}c^2}(\hat{\Omega}\cdot\hat{\Omega}'-1)=-(1-\hat{\Omega{'}}\cdot{\beta})-\frac{h\nu}{\gamma{m_e}c^2}(1-\hat{\Omega}\cdot\hat{\Omega}')$, and so we have

$$\frac{\nu{'}}{\nu}=\frac{-(1-\hat{\Omega}\cdot{\beta})}{-(1-\hat{\Omega{'}}\cdot{\beta})-\frac{h\nu}{\gamma{m_e}c^2}(1-\hat{\Omega}\cdot\hat{\Omega}')}=\frac{(1-\hat{\Omega}\cdot{\beta})}{(1-\hat{\Omega{'}}\cdot{\beta})+\frac{h\nu}{\gamma{m_e}c^2}(1-\hat{\Omega}\cdot\hat{\Omega}')}$$

where we have used the distributive property to extract $-1$ in the denominator.

Comment: Thank you. Very painless! Just couldn't get my brain into gear.